# Problem with differentiator ampilfier

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am currently building a PID controller using operational amplifiers. I thought yesterday that everything works, today I made the source (VPWL_FILE V2) from a second degree mathematical function to a step function, meaning: if t<0 seconds then 0V, else 4V.
Now I have found out that the operational amplifier with a differentiating basic circuit unfortunately does a bit of crap. How can it be that it outputs -4.7V for 3.3 seconds? It should output 0 Volts. I've already set the capacitor to 1e-4 F and increased the resistor accordingly – that didn't help either.

R4 is to reduce noise.

I set the initial voltage to 0V (I always do this in projects), but changing it to VMAX didn't help either.

[image: schematic]

[image: simulation results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the initial condition the capacitor C2 is practically discharged (only the input voltage offset determines its charge). R5 determines the charge and discharge time (RC = 3.8s).

Since the voltage across the capacitor doesn't change instantly, these are the voltages immediately after the 4V input pulse:

[image]

This means that the op.amp. will saturate close to the negative rail while the capacitor charges.

Comment: OK thank you. I got that now. Is it the case that this only occurs at the very first "start" of the circuit?

Comment: It occurs because a "step input" is being applied to the differentiator and this is how it reacts to this high derivative. If this input only happens at power up, yes (and you could handle it elsewhere). Anyway, you should also take into account other issues like the "initial conditions" when you quickly turn the circuit off and on again.

Comment: So that means this is the desired behavior on the step input?

Comment: It is the _expected_ behavior since the circuit has an output which is proportional to the derivative of the input signal and a very high derivative is being applied.

Comment: How big would you make R*C? (I know, it depends on the device in which this circuit is built in, but for testing purposes?)
I appreciate that, thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry, but how could I recommend a value for the D action in your PID controller within the scope of the question which is an explanation for the op. amp. saturation?

Comment: Ok, that's true.